# Nginx Domain name setup for LAN

Tags: nginx, lan

I have a web application running on my linux machine that is accessible at all other network machines via IP address x.x.x.x:3001. I want to use a domain name like myfun.fun  so that it can be accessible with this domain name throughout the network. I am new to Nginx, can somebody tell me what actually I have to do in order to acheive that?

Answer (score 0):

In Apache, you would call this a `vhost`. Nginx doesn't really have that, it's called a server block.

You can read more in the docs at https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/

Specifically, you need to add this to your config:

```
  server {
    server_name myfun.fun;
    access_log logs/myfun.fun.access.log main;

    root /var/www/myfun.fun/htdocs;
  }
```

Of course, you need to register your domain name myfun.fun and provide DNS records that point to your nginx server.